# USB Linux with Wireless support

Tags: wifi, live-usb

My friend has a laptop without HDD. I have installed Slax to a USB stick however it didn't recognize the wireless adapter. Are there any thumb Linuxes with support of variety wireless cards? I suspect that the wireless adapter is Broadcom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most any distro like Ubuntu, Fedora etc. will probably recognize the card and there are a variety of tools to install them unto USB drives.

Comment: Lubuntu has worked fine.